# Why do I see "Object of class __NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place" in this simple Monotouch code?

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, xamarin.ios, webclient

Monotouch 5.0.2.

Running the simple code below I get this in the output panel:

```
objc[20283]: Object 0x9c08110 of class __NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking - break on objc_autoreleaseNoPool() to debug
objc[20283]: Object 0x9c07840 of class __NSCFData autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking - break on objc_autoreleaseNoPool() to debug
```

Which NSStrings are leaking here and why? It seems to be enough to just create a new Uri() and a new WebClient() objetc. The event handler doesn't even have to be attached.

```
using System;
using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

namespace DownloadTest
{
    [Register ("AppDelegate")]
    public partial class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate
    { 
        UIWindow window;

        public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            window = new UIWindow (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);

            UIButton btn = UIButton.FromType (UIButtonType.RoundedRect);
            btn.Frame = new System.Drawing.RectangleF (40, 40, 100, 30);
            btn.TouchUpInside += delegate {
                // These two lines seem to caus the leak.
                Uri uri = new Uri ("http://silverlightinaction.com/video3.wmv");
                WebClient webClient = new WebClient ();
                // This line does not matter, the info about the leaking NSString alsp appears without an event being attached.
                webClient.OpenReadAsync (uri);                             
            };
            window.AddSubview (btn);

            window.MakeKeyAndVisible ();

            return true;
        }

        void HandleWebClientOpenReadCompleted (object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            using (var pool = new NSAutoreleasePool())
            {
                using (Stream stream = e.Result)
                using (FileStream fileStream = File.OpenWrite(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "download.bin")))
                {
                    stream.CopyTo (fileStream, 30000);
                    stream.Close ();
                    fileStream.Close ();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like a duplicate for http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1999 but we did not have a complete test case to duplicate it (your's work perfectly :-). I'll link the issue with it and track this down. Thanks

Comment: Somebody's happy about my misery! Great! Please send me a free cake for Christmas! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a MonoTouch bug. `WebClient` uses `Thread` which does not *automagically* creates an `NSAutoreleasePool` around the code being executed (e.g. like you did in your delegate). That can cause some leaks - just like you're seeing with the warning messages.

Note that using (threads from) `ThreadPool` is already ensuring that an `NSAutoreleasePool` covers the thread's execution.

Comment: It will be fixed, one way (`WebClient`) or another (`Thread`, my preference) since this cannot be fixed in user code (at least not without using `HttpWebRequest` instead of `WebClient`)

Answer (score 1):

I created a new class deriving from WebClient and overrode the "OnDownloadedCompleted" and created my own pool within a using block.  This seemed to get rid of the debug messages, not sure if it's the perfect fix though.

```
using(var a = new MonoTouch.Foundation.NSAutoreleasePool())
{
    base.OnDownloadDataCompleted (args);
}
```